# Is it possible to recover head pointer of a single linked list?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, linked-list

If the following assumptions can be made, is it possible to recover the head node of a linked list.

1. The linked list is created using malloc and it can be accessed from heap area.
2. The heap start and end address can be found from /proc/self/maps (at least in Linux).
3. At least one node in the original linked list is accessible.
4. The pointer to the previous node will be found in the heap somewhere.
5. And it can be recursively searched until the actual head is found.

To illustrate it better, please use the following program which can be compiled successfully with gcc under at-least Ubuntu/WSL under default configurations.

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;
node_t *head = NULL;
unsigned long start_address = 0;
unsigned long end_address = 0;

node_t *getLastNode()
{
    node_t *iter = head;
    for (; iter->next != NULL; iter = iter->next)
        ;
    return iter;
}
void addToLinkedList(int value)
{
    node_t *data = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    data->val = value;
    data->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = data;
    else
        getLastNode()->next = data;
}

void createLinkedList()
{
    // Add 10 nodes to the linked list
    int start_val = 0x10101010;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        addToLinkedList(start_val * i);
}

void printLinkedList()
{
    printf("Head pointer of Linked List : %p\n", head);
    for (node_t *iter = head; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next)
        printf("%p -> value = %X, next = %p \n", iter, iter->val, iter->next);
    printf("\n");
}

void resetHeadPtr()
{
    // Lets make head point to the last node
    head = getLastNode();
}

void findHeapBoundary()
{
    // Code inspired from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251769/152334
    char mapsFilename[1024];
    char line[256];

    char area[1024];
    sprintf(mapsFilename, "/proc/%d/maps", getpid());
    FILE *pMapsFile = fopen(mapsFilename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, 256, pMapsFile) != NULL)
    {
        // Dirty hack to get the heap start and end address
        sscanf(line, "%08lx-%08lx%*[^[]%s\n", &start_address, &end_address, area);
        if (strcmp(area, "[heap]") == 0)
            break;
    }
    fclose(pMapsFile);
    printf("Heap memory start address : %p\n", (int *)start_address);
    printf("Heap memory end address   : %p\n", (int *)end_address);
}

node_t *findPointerInMemory()
{
    for (int *ptr = (int *)start_address; ptr < (int *)(end_address - sizeof(node_t)); ptr++)
    {
        if (((node_t *)ptr)->next == head)
            return (node_t *)ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void recoverHeadPtr()
{
    node_t *ptr = findPointerInMemory();
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot find %p in heap memory\nStopping Search\n\n", head);
        return;
    }
    printf("Found %p at %p\n", head, ptr);
    head = ptr;
    recoverHeadPtr();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    createLinkedList();
    printf("Original Linked List Contents\n*****************************\n");
    printLinkedList();

    resetHeadPtr();
    printf("Linked List Contents after reset\n********************************\n");
    printLinkedList();

    findHeapBoundary();
    recoverHeadPtr();

    printf("Recovered Linked List Contents\n******************************\n");
    printLinkedList();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Original Linked List Contents
*****************************
Head pointer of Linked List : 0x1db6010
0x1db6010 -> value = 10101010, next = 0x1db6030
0x1db6030 -> value = 20202020, next = 0x1db6050
0x1db6050 -> value = 30303030, next = 0x1db6070
0x1db6070 -> value = 40404040, next = 0x1db6090
0x1db6090 -> value = 50505050, next = 0x1db60b0
0x1db60b0 -> value = 60606060, next = 0x1db60d0
0x1db60d0 -> value = 70707070, next = 0x1db60f0
0x1db60f0 -> value = 80808080, next = 0x1db6110
0x1db6110 -> value = 90909090, next = 0x1db6130
0x1db6130 -> value = A0A0A0A0, next = (nil)

Linked List Contents after reset
********************************
Head pointer of Linked List : 0x1db6130
0x1db6130 -> value = A0A0A0A0, next = (nil)

Heap memory start address : 0x1db6000
Heap memory end address   : 0x1dd7000
Found 0x1db6130 at 0x1db6110
Found 0x1db6110 at 0x1db60f0
Found 0x1db60f0 at 0x1db60d0
Found 0x1db60d0 at 0x1db60b0
Found 0x1db60b0 at 0x1db6090
Found 0x1db6090 at 0x1db6070
Found 0x1db6070 at 0x1db6050
Found 0x1db6050 at 0x1db6030
Found 0x1db6030 at 0x1db6010
Cannot find 0x1db6010 in heap memory
Stopping Search

Recovered Linked List Contents
******************************
Head pointer of Linked List : 0x1db6010
0x1db6010 -> value = 10101010, next = 0x1db6030
0x1db6030 -> value = 20202020, next = 0x1db6050
0x1db6050 -> value = 30303030, next = 0x1db6070
0x1db6070 -> value = 40404040, next = 0x1db6090
0x1db6090 -> value = 50505050, next = 0x1db60b0
0x1db60b0 -> value = 60606060, next = 0x1db60d0
0x1db60d0 -> value = 70707070, next = 0x1db60f0
0x1db60f0 -> value = 80808080, next = 0x1db6110
0x1db6110 -> value = 90909090, next = 0x1db6130
0x1db6130 -> value = A0A0A0A0, next = (nil)
```

**Background**

A friend of mine was asked the following question in an interview. “Can you find the head pointer of a single linked list if the last node is given?”. He answered “no” and even though the interviewer was not entirely satisfied with the answer, he was offered the job. This got me into thinking, whether it is possible do this.

**So, the real questions are.**

1. Is this approach correct?
2. Do we need to search in other memory segments?
3. Can this approach be generalized to work on Windows too?
4. Will ASLR have any impact on this approach?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Practical? No. And it would break a lot of rules set out in the C specification.

Comment: looking up the previous node in memory with the `next` value, would wield some false positive

Comment: If your appl. evaluates the "private" heap organization which is managed by `malloc()` and companions it might be possible. (Tools like Valgrind surely does it this way.) Beyond this, I would vote for "No" as well.

Comment: That code is not reliable (among other issues) because the fact that you find a value which happens to be the same bits as an address means very little. It could be an integer or a floating point number which just happens to have the right bit pattern. Or, more likely, it could be an actual pointer to that same address, except that the pointer is in the memory which had been allocated to an object which has been freed along with the thing it used to point at.

Comment: You would narrow it down far more if you understood the meta data used by malloc and only searched blocks of sizeof(node_t) bytes and only allocated blocks. The last part will be very important because removing one element from the head of the list will leave the old node_t in memory giving you a false hit.

Comment: False assumption that there is a single heap section. Most allocators when queried for allocations larger than `PAGE_SIZE` usually call `mmap` rather than using `brk`. So the allocations might not necessarily be in the `heap` entry of `/proc/self/maps`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer would have been:

Not cleanly and attempting to do so would be a risky workaround for a bad design.
If you actually do try to search for the address of anything in memory (which is not in any way guaranteed to only contain the address if it is the pointer in question), then you might find instead any piece of memory which seems to accidentally contain a number which looks like the address in question.
If you then continue using that, assuming it to be the pointer, you are inviting all kinds of problems.
If you do that repeatedly to go backwards through a single-linked list, then you practically guarantee to find at least one nonsense.

In short: No.

A simple "No." is too short and might have made the examiner frown because of that.

Answer (score 0):

In standard C  it's not possible.

accessing the heap other than via pointers given by malloc (or copies of those pointers etc) will get you undefined behaviour.

However if you have knowledge of the allocator and can walk the structure of the allocated memory blocks you can find candidate list nodes. one of them will be the head.